# The error $|x_{k+1}-x^*|=|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|=|g'(\xi)(x_k-x^*)| $ with fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Today I had a lecture about fixed point iteration.
We have a $g(x)$ with one fixed point $x^*$ and a $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ on interval $[a,b]$.

During the lecture my professor talked about the error $|x_{k+1}-x^*|=|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|=|g'(\xi)(x_k-x^*)|$. I don't really see how he made the last step.

I tried to find it myself but I didn't get the same outcome.
What I tried:

$|x_{k+1}-x^*|=|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|$  because of Taylor we have that,
$g(x_k)=g(x^*)+\frac{g'(x*)}{1}(x_k-x*)+...+\frac{g'^r(x^*)}{r!}(x_k-x^*)^r+\frac{g'^{r+1}(\xi)}{\xi!}(x_k-x^*)^{r+1}$

$g(x^*)=x^*$ so $g'(x^*)=0$, so a lot of terms are $0$. This leaves us $g(x_k)=g(x^*)+\frac{g'^{r+1}(\xi)}{\xi!}(x_k-x^*)^{r+1}$

I thought $r=1$ because we have $1$ fixed point.But that gives me $g(x_k)=g(x^*)+\frac{g"(\xi)}{\xi!}(x_k-x^*)^{2}$. And than we would get $ |g(x_k)-g(x^*)|= \frac{g"(\xi)}{\xi!}(x_k-x^*)^{2}$

So something went wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you get $g'(x^*)=0$? In general that is not the case, and a bound on $g'$ is used to investigate contractivity quantitatively.

Comment: Oh yes I made a mistake there... We have that $g(x^*)=x^*$, so $g'(x^*)=1$ right?

Comment: No, of course not, $x^*$ is an isolated fixed point, thus $g(x)=x$ is not true outside $x=x^*$. Contrarily you want $|g'(x^*)|<1$ for contractivity.

Answer (score 0):

He assumes differentiability of $g$ and uses the Mean Value theorem, so $\xi$ is a point between $x_k$ and $x^*$.